# Error when inserting Description Column

Tags: sql, spotfire

Below is my code that I have to add a description column in Spotfire. It works well in Microsoft SQL.How am I supposed to write it in Spotfire?

```
SELECT
   v1."DateTime" AS "DISCRETELIVEDATETIME",
   v1."TagName" AS "DISCRETELIVETAGNAME",
   v1."Value" AS "DISCRETELIVEVALUE",
   v2.Description AS "DESCRIPTION"
FROM
   "Runtime"."dbo"."v_DiscreteLive" v1 
INNER JOIN [Runtime].[dbo].Tag v2 ON v1.TagName = v2.TagName
```

The above is the code I made that is giving me the error below.

```
Error message: Failed to execute data source query.

ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute data source query. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.Execute()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.DataFlowConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.<>c__DisplayClass11.<GetColumnsAndProperties>b__e()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.GetColumnsAndProperties(DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.PerformUpdate(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.Update(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataPool.<LoadData>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.<Refresh>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable.<>c__DisplayClass66.<>c__DisplayClass69.<BeginRefresh>b__62()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.INode.InternalTransaction(Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable.<>c__DisplayClass66.<BeginRefresh>b__60()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.Transaction(Executor executor, Boolean visible, Boolean sticky, Guid stickyGuid)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.StickyTransaction(Guid guid, Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.StickyTransaction(Guid guid, Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.ITransactions.ExecuteStickyTransaction(Guid guid, Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable.BeginRefresh(Boolean showDataLoadReport)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable.Refresh(Boolean showDataLoadReport)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.RefreshProducers(IEnumerable`1 tablesToRefresh, Boolean showDataLoadReport)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.Refresh(IEnumerable`1 tablesToRefresh)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.DataFormsUserActions.<>c__DisplayClassc.<RefreshData>b__a()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.DoOperationLoop()


InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute query: Incorrect syntax near 'v2'. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Internal.Utilities.SeekableStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadUInt16()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formats.Sbdf.SbdfSectionHeader.ReadSectionType(BinaryReader reader, SbdfSectionTypeId expectedType)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.SbdfDataRowReader.DelayedInit()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSourceConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()


InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services:
Failed to execute query: Incorrect syntax near 'v2'. (HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.WebServiceBase`1.InvokeService[T](ServiceMethod`1 serviceMethod, ExceptionFactoryMethod exceptionFactoryMethod)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()
```

Comment: why are you changing from putting object in "quotes" to putting them in [brackets]? I don't know Spotfire but I suspect that is your problem - SQL Server allows either but Spotfire probably doesn't. Dunno if you need to use `v2."Description"` in the select part too

Comment: I'd like to know more about how you're executing this query in Spotfire. Are you using Information Designer, or are you doing an in-database connection? If you could post a screenshot maybe I could help.

Comment: what version of Spotfire are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are changing the sql query. I think you are only able to add where clause. If you want to add a column you must model it in the information designer.